# Getting type parameters at runtime

Tags: c++, c++11

I have a class that uses variadic type parameters that can be only known at runtime when a user types input. The type parameters must be only a `int` or `string` and must be 1 or many (which is why there is `Key and`Keys).

```
using namespace std;

using Column = boost::variant<vector<int>, vector<string>>;
using Columns = vector<Column>;

namespace db {
    template <typename Key, typename... Keys>
    class KeyedTable {
    public:
        KeyedTable(const string& name);

        template<typename V>
        void add(const int pos, const V val, Key k1, Keys... keys);

        string toString();
    private:
        string name;
        vector<string> colNames;
        map<tuple<Key, Keys...>, Columns> data;
    };
}
```

I must create an instance of this class from a `vector<Expr>` where each Expr represents the type parameter and the length of the `vector` represents the number of type parameters needed:

```
class Expr {}

class IntExpr : public Expr {public: int i;}

class StringExpr : public Expr {public: string s;}
```

What's the best solution to work with this class when the type and number of  type parameters are known only at runtime?

Comment: Variadic templates and runtime type deduction sounds a bit contradictorily for me.

Comment: Ship a C++ compiler, use user input to generate C++ code, compile said code and run it?  (this may also be the worst way to solve your problem)

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is impossible to do. Templates are resolved during compilation time. This means all overloads are generated then. You cannot "add" new functions with different number of arguments on the fly when you get new input. *(Well maybe, technically somehow possible but it goes beyond standard c++)*.

If it's known in runtime do it in runtime. You cannot mix compile time logic with runtime logic.

What would you expect to happen if your input had zero keys?

I think you will need something like `map<vector<KeyType>, Columns> data`. You already have a vector for `Columns` so it would even seem somewhat natural.